# How do I write below code in Java 8 using Stream API?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there any way to write the following code using `Stream`s?

```
public Map<String, Integer> process() {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(message.toLowerCase().split("[?.\\s]+"));
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() > 2) {
            Integer count = countMap.getOrDefault(word, 0);
            countMap.put(word, count + 1);
        }
    }
    return countMap;
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to count words which are have greater than 2 characters.

Comment: It should be like this `Pattern.compile("[?.\\s]+").splitAsStream(message.toLowerCase())
        .filter(w -> w.length() > 2).count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` to generate the `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> countMap =
    words.stream()
         .filter(word -> word.length() > 2)
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),w -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Of course you can skip `Arrays.asList` and create a `Stream` directly from the array:

```
Map<String, Integer> countMap =
    Arrays.stream (message.toLowerCase().split("[?.\\s]+"))
          .filter(word -> word.length() > 2)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),w -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Comment: hey can you explain me how do these parameters execute (w -> 1, Integer::sum)

Answer (score 3):

Start out with

```
Pattern.compile("[?.\\s]+").splitAsStream(message.toLowerCase())
```

if you can live with a long result, stick with Ravindra's solution, if you need int, use Eran's counter.

So either:

```
Map<String, Long> r = Pattern.compile("[?.\\s]+").splitAsStream(message.toLowerCase())
    .filter(w -> w.length() > 2)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

or

```
Map<String, Integer> r = Pattern.compile("[?.\\s]+").splitAsStream(message.toLowerCase())
    .filter(w -> w.length() > 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), w -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

or (after the comment below) (even better)

```
Map<String, Integer> r = Pattern.compile("[?.\\s]+").splitAsStream(message.toLowerCase())
    .filter(w -> w.length() > 2)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));
```

Comment: instead `Collectors.counting()` use `Collectors.summingInt(e->1)`

Comment: @HadiJ Thanks, included in the answer.

Comment: Nice answer @mtj

Comment: Alternatively `Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), Long::intValue))`

Comment: Thanks, that helped :)